# Why can't you award exemplary answer bounties right away?

Tags: feature-request, bounty-awards

I understand requiring a delay when offering a bounty because a question hasn't received enough attention, but why require a 24-hour delay on exemplary answer bounties?

Comment: this is discussed in details in this MSO post (and in other posts linked to it): **[Should the 24-hour timeout apply to bounties awarded for “exemplary answer”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/165773)** I for one try to keep my exemplary-answer bounties for as long as possible, [to let great answers collect more eyeballs, along with hopefully some more upvotes from readers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155887/165773 "as explained here")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of bothered me [when I wanted to award a bounty here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716736/smart-variadic-expansion-based-on-format-string). I've already got the answer in mind that I want to reward, I'm *not* likely to give it to any other answer, and the bounty can't be refunded - so why wait?

I'll bring this up on a feature call in the near future, but we're a bit backlogged on those, so please be patient (Next week? probably not. This month? probably.)

Comment: Okay, I lied, we're _having_ a call this week it seems, and it's on the agenda.